# How to make cookie access for entire root folder

Tags: php, cookies

I want to make the cookie accessible for the entire root folder, how can I do it ??

```
<?php
$value="test";
setcookie("test",$value, time()+3600, '/', NULL, 0 );        
if($_COOKIE['test']=="test")
{
echo 'ok';
}
else
{
echo 'not ok';
}
```

It works only for the particular folder where the cookie is declared ,

```
  ie., localhost\proj\app\views\settings\client*
```

but I want to make accessible on the folder

```
  localhost\proj\app\views\*
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies can be restricted by allowing only sub domain access,to make cookie available for all set its domain to *.domain.com.

Comment: Thanks it worked, i made as setcookie("test",$value, time()+3600, '*/', NULL, 0 );

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is

> setcookie(cookieName, cookieValue, time()+31557600, '/',
>   '.domain.com');

When I tried with wildcard it didn't work, but as per official php.net documentation

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

You just need to put a single slash as the path and .domainname.extension as the domain.